# How to use theme colors in ant design?

Tags: reactjs, antd

I want to use the primary color from the ant design theme. I believe the less tag is: `@primary-color` . How do I use this value for a custom div that I want the border color to match? Also this is with an app made by create-react-app.

I want to be able to do something like:

```
border: '2px solid #fff' // Instead of white, it uses the theme's primary color
```

Answer (score 1):

In the very top of your .less file import Ant Design styles: @import '~antd/dist/antd.less';

And then you can use any antd color variable:

```
@import '~antd/dist/antd.less';

.box {
    border: 2px solid @primary-color;
}
```